# Polar ble device not found

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing a new application that should display a heart rate value
using "Polar" device.
I have downloaded a sample application from 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Phone Bluetooth connection recognizes "Polar" device and I paired it with the
phone.

The application succeed to find several devices, 
but doesn't find "Polar" device. Some of the application that I downloaded from android market succeed to do so.

I'm clueless and can't find out that is the difference between the heart rate ble device to others.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Which version the the Polar HRM do you have, as you nee one that supports Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy (BLE / Smart) to utilise that app. Polar made this switch from Bluetooth to Bluetooth 4.0 Smart with the H6, so if you have an H5 or earlier you'll want some older vanilla Bluetooth code.